# How to avoid "Last set context:" messages after using .cxr

Tags: debugging, windbg, postmortem-debugging

When analyzing a dump, I had to `.cxr` to get to the real exception call stack.

Almost every command I run has "Last set context:" in the output. This is very annoying, especially when running scripts (getting a lot of these messages between and within the output lines of the script).

Is there any way to avoid/suppress those messages or maybe create a new dump from the existing dump where the exception context is the only context?